# I am attempting to implement a dropdown menu on my navigation but it isn't displaying the way I'd like it too. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

Yes.. A re-post because apparently my last question didn't make much sense. The current navigation I have is this http://www.nerdcrown.net - and after putting in the code for the drop down, I get this http://www.fantasy-anime.com/nerdcrown/ . The drop down seems functional, but I don't know how to make it look like the original. (fantasy-anime is just my test site)

To clarify, what I want is to have the navigation in the first link, look the exact same.. Just be used as a drop down. I can include the code I've used for both. I'd like to know what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong. Here is the original coding, used in the healthy looking menu.

```css
/*menu*/
.menu { padding:0; margin:0; float:right; width:530px;}
.menu ul { text-align: left;  padding:15px 0 0 0; margin:0; list-style:none; border:0; float:right;}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:13px 5px; border:0; }
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:0; padding:13px 0 13px 0; color:#5e5e5e; font:bold 14px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; }
.menu ul li a span { padding:13px 10px; background:none; }
.menu ul li a:hover { color:#fff; background: url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right; }
.menu ul li a:hover span {color:#fff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left; }
.menu ul li a.active { color:#fff;  background:url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right; }
.menu ul li a.active span { color:#fff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left; }
/* search */
```

Here is the unhealthy code. It functions properly, but I can't seem to make it look like the first.

```css
/*menu*/
{
width:auto !important;
margin:0;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(../../../images/headerlinks_sprite.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
margin: 0 7px;
display:inline; 
}

#menu li a {
display:inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url(../../../images/headerlinks_sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 }
#menu li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#menu li ul{display:none;}
#menu li:hover ul{display:block;}
#menu li ul li, #nav li ul li a
{
display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
}
```

Comment: could you be more specific with your question? maybe something like you're trying to create a dropdown menu and it is not displaying properly? also, your code snippets doesn't seem of much use here

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I am trying to create a dropdown menu from what I already had. What I have currently is visible at http://www.nerdcrown.net

Comment: However.. I was told by an individual to use a certain code for the CSS to fix that. Now. I've started tampering with it, which the progress can be seen at http://www.fantasy-anime.com/nerdcrown/ . Unfortunately.. I cannot make it look like the original navigation. That is what I'm asking for help with. What am I missing in the code?

Comment: I would advise against using code you don't understand ;) how about looking for a tutorial on building a dropdown menu? for example this one at [teamtreehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-simple-css-dropdown-menu) or any other you find easy to follow

Comment: If you're not going to at least try to help me, you don't have to be rude ;). I've gone through all of the tutorials, I came here because this is one-on-one and I was hoping for people to at least help me figure out the issue. Redirecting someone to another website isn't all that ideal. If you're incapable of helping, that's fine -- no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a great example of nested lists styled with CSS for a dropdown menu here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That is actually a lot more helpful, the code is a lot cleaner. Unfortunately it removes the hovering. On the dropdown menu I was working on, hovering over the navigation button would display the dropdown options in the menu. But that still doesn't help me figure out how to make the dropdown menu look like the menu I have on http://www.nerdcrown.net . Also, I'm having some weird issue that I can't really explain. If I could trouble you to visit the test site I'm working with right now http://www.fantasy-anime.com/nerdcrown/ . Either way, I appreciate the help you've given thus far.

Comment: This is how I want it to look. 
http://prntscr.com/8wlbzd
This is how it looks right now
http://prntscr.com/8wlc8r

Comment: This is the current progress http://www.fantasy-anime.com/nerdcrown/ but unforunately.. It still doesn't look the way I want it to. I've displayed the way I want it to look already.